# How to pass object field in DAO?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, dao

I created DAOs for my entities. And now I have a problem: I need to pass another object's field in some methods. For example:

```
@Override
public void updateById(PriceTrack priceTrack, int id) throws DBException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_BY_ID);
        ps.setInt(1, priceTrack.getOldPrice());
        ps.setInt(2, priceTrack.getNewPrice());
        ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(priceTrack.getLastUpdatedPrice().getTime()));
        // todo - pass Appartment id
        ps.setObject(4, new Apartment());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JdbcUtils.rollbackQuitely(conn);
        throw new DBException("Cannot execute SQL = '" + UPDATE_BY_ID + "'", e);
    } finally {
        JdbcUtils.closeQuitely(ps);
        JdbcUtils.closeQuitely(conn);
    }
}
```

Here I need to pass the corresponding `Aparment_id` value. Creating `new Apartment()` is wrong.

Content of `UPDATE_BY_ID`:

```
    public static final String UPDATE_BY_ID = "UPDATE price_track SET old_price=?, new_price=?, lastupdated_price=?, apartment_id=?";
```

What is the best way to do it?

Here is also the diagram, that shows connection.
[image]

Comment: Show the content of `UPDATE_BY_ID`.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: I think it is not clear what you are trying to do. You would like to change the `aparment_id` fo one price_track record or you try to create a new one??

Comment: do you use an ORM like hibernate?

Comment: no i want to understand, how it works on jdbc level, and only then add hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a concern with the growing number of arguments there are possible solutions:

1. To pass a map in which you can pass the number of arguments you want in the form of key-value pair as required
2. To pass a object when the arguments being passed are many and basically a part of the form which correlate to fields of a class and supplied to you in the form of an populated object

Which case you go for depends on the way you are getting data and what is anticipation of getting more fields in future.

Comment: I don't have a lot of arguments, so I think the second way will be right. Can you explain in detail please?
How to pass corresponding `Apartment` object there?

Comment: Are you using a specialized form tag like spring form tag or struts form tag on the view

Comment: I did not do view yet, but I will use struts form tag.

Comment: In case of struts 2, you can go for modeldriven approach. http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-modeldriven-example/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update `old_price`, `new_price` or `lastupdated_price` it is not necessarily update `aparment_id` because it is foreign key. It is logical to assume that it won't change. You can remove `aparment_id` from your query:

```
UPDATE price_track SET old_price=?, new_price=?, lastupdated_price=?
```

And appropriately remove `ps.setObject(4, new Apartment());` from your code.

JDBC requires manual configuration and it does nothing automatically.

Comment: Okay I agree, but this problem will appear when I will create a new price track. There I will have to set a proper apartment object.

Comment: You don't have to do this in update method, first you need to save Apartment and further to save PriceTrack using aparment_id instead of Apartment object.

Comment: I don't have to do it in `update` method but I have to do it in `void create(Apartment apartment)` method. And also `apartment_id` has auto-increment.

Comment: If apartment_id has auto-increment you can don't specify the parameter `apartment_id` in the sql query when you create apartment. But if you need to get this `apartment_id` you have to do additional query to DB or to manage the appointment apartment_id at the application level, and don't use auto-increment

Comment: when i create an apartment - sure, I don't need to specify it, but i need to specify `apartment_id` when I create `PriceTrack`, because `price_track` has a foreign key `apartment_id`.

Comment: At the time when you create `PriceTrack` `Appartment` has been created and corresponding record is already in the database. You can get the value `apartment_id` from the database and specify it when you create`PriceTrack`

Comment: Do you mean that in `create` method I need to execute query that selects apartment by id and then use its value?

Comment: Yes, as an option If you previously did not have this value in the code

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to create object, initialize it and pass it to DAO.
For that use POJO class:

```
class PriceTrack{
           int id;
           doulbe price;
          //and relation ship between price and apartment 1:1 or 1:n
            Set apartment=new HashSet(0);
         //getter and setter
     }

class Apartment{
           int id;
           int room;
           String description;
         //and relation ship between apartment and price 1:1 or 1:n
      }

public static void main(String s[])
{
   PriceTrack priceTrack=new PriceTrack();
  priceTrack.setId(23);
   priceTrack.setPrice(2389);
  Apartment a=new Apartment();
  a.setRoom(3);
  a.setDescription("good rooms");
  Set s=new HashSet();
  s.add(a);
  priceTrack.setApartment(s);
  //now send It to the DAO method
  DAO.updateById(priceTrack);
}
```